# Can you use LINQ to do a process such as converting part of a list and assigning to another?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to parse the strings in a part of an array to doubles, then assign them to a part of another array.

```
public static void SetRange(double[] inputs, int numberOfInputs, int inputsOffset, int stringsOffset, string[] strings)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < numberOfInputs; j++)
    {
        inputs[j + inputsOffset] = double.Parse(strings[j + stringsOffset]);
    } 
}
```

Can you do something like this? Obviously I've made up the 'Do' method.

```
Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfInputs).Do(j => inputs[j + inputsOffset] = double.Parse(strings[j + stringsOffset]));
```

Comment: Replace `Do` with `ForEach`

Comment: can you show me an expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfInputs)
          .ToList()
          .ForEach(j => inputs[j + inputsOffset] = double.Parse(strings[j + stringsOffset]));
```

Comment: `Foreach` is exactly what I am looking for, that works elegantly, thanks @Christos